# paste web application directory in /var/www permission error

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I want to copy php web application directory from windows partition

> C:/wamp/www/gestion

to Ubuntu partition /var/www, I get this message

> the folder "gestion" cannot be copied because you do not have permissions to create it in the destination

in the terminal I have executed

> sudo chmod -R a+rwx /var/www

but always same error message
I have displayed ls-l in var folder I have :

> drwxrwxrwx  3 root root     4096 janv. 18 16:18 www

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/
```

WARNING!!! This is a security risk. Change it to a more secure permissions structure once you are done.